# Xamarin/Cosmos DB Design question Service intermediary or not? (Design Question)

Tags: ios, api, xamarin, azure-cosmosdb, webapi

Traditionally in Xamarin apps I have written in the past there is a WebService that creates calls using EF or just stored Procs to talk to relational Database. In the Brave new World of Cosmos Am I being relieved of providing that extra service layer of Database connectivity software?

Answer (score 0):

Exposing a database publicly in the Web is always risky, it's a bit challenging to garantee the security of your data tier if your dB is exposed publicly.

What happens if someone use the men-in-the-middle attack or any other attack to steal your dB-credentials? He will get access to all your data (even the data you app is hiding from your users) and can any undesirable operation granted to dB account. So, having an application server between the app and the data tier will add an additional security layer to you app if designed carefully.

Another interesting point is the fact that a Web service can implement different mechanisms to control what users are allowed to do with your data - using RBAC for example, if this kind of controls are implemented in the mobile app where the source code can be reverse ingenieered, it can be easier for an attacker to bypass your controls and do whatever he want to do with your app.

Using a web service helps you having more control on your infrastructure and how you want it to grow, for example, scaling a web server is easier and costless than scaling a database server.

Comment: realizing that Cosmos has an offline / online resynch made for mobile apps. If you put the service in how do you enable that feature?

Comment: Mobile apps supports only Azure SQL on the server side. Where did you find info on Cosmos DB for this purpose?

Comment: @MarkWardell, it&#39;s hard to develop an intermediate layer between your sync server and your app, in this scenario you can use the api provided by cosmosdb, but the risk of having your dB credentials steal is there, I would use Azure Key Vault to fetch the database credentials at least on the first run if you are supporting offline mode.

Comment: @ravitella I think Mark is taking about something similar to this https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/tree/master/samples/xamarin/ToDoItems/ToDoItems.Core

Comment: @SamirChakour There is nothing native in the Cosmos DB APIs or the SDK to help with the offline sync. It will have to be a custom implementation from scratch. On the other hand, Azure Mobile apps does provide a SDK and server side API called the Sync table API to help with the offline sync. Azure Mobile apps can only use SQL DB.

Comment: @ravitella here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mobile-apps-with-xamarin . there was the EZTables interface. Deprecated. Then there Was AppCenter Data now unfindable on AppCenter.  Is SyncTable API a part of either of these Missing In Action Products?

Comment: @MarkWardell Can you point me to the  EZTables interface for Cosmos DB? The link you shared does not have any reference to it.

Comment: @ravi tella. I am beginning to think we are miscommunicating. I am just discussing the long list of items that are being deprecated from Xamarin world. EZTables using SQLServer is no longer supported except for legacy created before. AppCenter was pushing its Data app. It is now gone.  However Cosmos, which also does not support EZTables I thought Had an offline mode for mobile developers. It seems to be a requested feature only. I hope Cosmos does support offline mode.

Comment: @MarkWardell finally we are communication right:). Sorry for the confusion. I also wish to see the offline mode support on both the server side and the SDK.

Comment: I talked to MS and there currently is no coverage for ofline/online in their solution stack. Cosmos Db does not have it. App Center (DATA) had it but it was deprecated prior to release. EZ Tables are now removed. There advice was to roll-your-own